# How to apply the vertical offset/shift properly in WKT

Tags: coordinate-system, datum, offset, vertical

We are trying to use a vertical offset in one of our WKT which is a GDA94/MGA zone 52 CRS by integrating the Australian Height Datum but it does not apply the vertical offset. I am wondering if we are doing it correctly or is there another way to apply the vertical offset on the said CRS. We are doing this because we are trying to map the underground mapping.

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS? or what software are you using?